# Log4J prevent HTTPClient from logging to MySQL

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using org.apache.http.client libraries and this has some default logging. I've also got log4j set up to handling my general logging and the http client logging.

The issue I have is that I don't want the http client logging going into the MySQL database.

Here is the properties file for log4j:
    #define the console appender
    log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

```
# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern==%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss} %p %t %c - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, debugTrack, DB
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG, debugTrack, DB
log4j.logger.infoLogger=INFO, infoTrack, DB
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=httpcomm
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=httpcomm

log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
log4j.additivity.infoLogger=false

log4j.appender.debugTrack=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugTrack.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.debugTrack.File=log//debugTrack.log
log4j.appender.debugTrack.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.debugTrack.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.debugTrack.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugTrack.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss} %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.infoTrack=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoTrack.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.infoTrack.File=log//infoTrack.log
log4j.appender.infoTrack.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.infoTrack.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.infoTrack.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoTrack.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss} %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.httpcomm=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.httpcomm.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.httpcomm.File=log//HTTPCommunication.log
log4j.appender.httpcomm.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.httpcomm.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.httpcomm.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.httpcomm.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss} %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://server/database
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=********
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO tbl_logs(logDate,logger,level,message) VALUES('%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C','%p','%m')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

There is an info logger and a debug logger that I wish to keep logging to file and to database. I also wish to keep the HTTP client logging to the file but NOT to the Database.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Many thanks
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `additivity` to `false` for the parent package, meaning nothing will propagate from there. To also get this behaviour for the `log4j.logger.org.apache.http` package, you need to set this too:

```
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
log4j.additivity.org.apache.http=false
log4j.additivity.infoLogger=false
```

Also note that there is no need to specify both `log4j.logger.org.apache.http` and `log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire`, the first one should cover both.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input, that makes sense and I have made the change. However, no I get the following message:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Accepted the answer now - I fixed my previous problem by ensuring I had the appenders properly defined. I had made some other changes that were not required.

Thanks for the help.